# How to migrate data from OpenTSDB to TDengine?

Tags: opentsdb, tdengine

I'm trying to migrate history data used to be stored in OpenTSDB to TDengine as I'm struggling with setting up multiple components like TSD, zookeeper etc. Does TDengine provide any ways to serve this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool named [taosAdapter](https://github.com/taosdata/taosadapter).

It is compatible with OpenTSDB JSON and Telnet format writing.

For historical data migration, you can try [DataX](https://github.com/alibaba/DataX).